# Share secure file(s) across team projects in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

The company I work for currently has several projects in TFS 2015, each with their own build definitions.
We are in the process of transitioning from TFS to VSTS.

One of the features of VSTS that we were trying to utilize in the builds is the Secure Files in the projects' Library, to store the certificate issued by our company used for digitally signing assets in different installers.
It is currently duplicated in each project.

We were planning on uploading the certificate to one project and then use the 'Download Secure File' task in all of the projects' builds (that need it), to eliminate the maintenance of having the same certificate in multiple projects.

Not surprisingly, after uploading to one project, the file is not listed in any other project's Library or available for download as part of the build, even if I try to assign the project(s)/team(s) as a security role to the secure file (even giving it Administrator role).

Is there a way to have a secure file in one project's Library be shared across other projects, so that it can be downloaded as part of a build task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a big secret that the VSTS team has been working towards making individual projects portable. To allow you to take a project, with all that belongs to it, and then move it to another account. No clue when or even if this will ever be released, but it serves as a basis behind some of the separation between separate team projects.

In order to make this seamless, direct links and dependencies between projects are actively being discouraged and old features that are cross-project are slowly disappearing from the UI (even if the API supports it in many cases).

I suspect that if you configure the builds scope to be "Collection" that the REST API will be able to access the secret file from the other project, but it would require a custom task.

The guidance would be to replicate the secret file to each team project that needs access to it.